# Set UITableView rows as selected if contained in an array

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have data stored in a realm database. I retrieve the information from the database and place it in an array. I then search through the array and set the cell to selected if it is contained in the array.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SubjectsTableViewCell

    var subject: Subjects!

    subject = Subjects[Int(indexPath.row)]

    cell.subject.text = subject.subjectTitle

    if chosenSubjects.contains(subject.subjectTitle) {

       cell.selected = true
       cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
       tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
        cell.highlighted = true

    } else  {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    }


    return cell

}
```

Unfortunately, the above code is giving me some strange results. Sometimes the cells are highlighted and display a checkmark, sometimes the first cell in the table is unhighlighted, but displays a checkmark. Sometimes I have to press the cell twice to deselect. Note, I have also set the didSelectRowAtIndexPath and didDeselectRowAtIndexPath as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubjectsTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark


}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
     let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubjectsTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .None


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this can occur because you are reusing cells with your line

`let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SubjectsTableViewCell`

Instead, try doing something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {

    let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! SubjectsTableViewCell

    var subject: Subjects!

    subject = Subjects[Int(indexPath.row)]

    cell.subject.text = subject.subjectTitle

    if chosenSubjects.contains(subject.subjectTitle) {

       cell.selected = true
       cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
       tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
       cell.highlighted = true

    } else  {

       cell.selected = false
       cell.accessoryType = .None
       cell.highlighted = false

       tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    }


    return cell

}
```

Hope this helps; let me know if it doesn't!

---

**Edit:**
I just noticed that within your select and deselect tableview functions, you don't actually update your chosenSubjects array for the given row. You need to update this before you call cellForRowAtIndexPath; otherwise, the if condition (in your cellForRowAtIndexPath) will fail - thus leading to the weird behaviour!

Try this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    var subject: Subjects! = Subjects[Int(indexPath.row)]
    chosenSubjects.addObject(subject.subjectTitle)

    let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubjectsTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark


}
```

and this:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Get the row data for the selected row
    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true

    var subject: Subjects! = Subjects[Int(indexPath.row)]
    chosenSubjects = chosenSubjects.filter() { $0 != subject.subjectTitle }

     let cell:SubjectsTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubjectsTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = .None
```

}

Comment: Tried that Jason, still getting strange behaviour. Some cells are selected with a checkmark and highlighted. Some are selected with the checkmark but not highlighted. Very frustrating, but there must be a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks Jason, almost there! The table loads with the correct subjects selected, however, when I try to deselect a selected subject I have to press twice initially. It's as if the tableview does not realise that some cells have been selected even though I've added the tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None) code to inform the tableview that the cell is selected.

Comment: Sorry, I made one small mistake - make sure you call "self.tableView.reloadData()" **in between** "chosenSubjects = ..." and "let cell: ..." **in both** the select and deselect functions. This makes sure that the tableView updates for the new given data.

Comment: Still getting this strange behaviour. The table loads with the correct items selected, however, the table's datasource doesn't know because when I click on a "selected item" didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called rather than didDeselectRowAtIndexPath. My thoughts are that I'll need to change the code to use one datasource, i.e. the database rather than use the database and the array.

Comment: Hmm give that a try and let me know if it works. Quite a perplexing problem!

Answer (score 0):

var userCLient = string is an empty string array declare..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedRow:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

        if selectedRow.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none{
            selectedRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
            selectedRow.tintColor = UIColor.green
            var dict = arrRes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            let EmpID = dict["user_id"] as? Int
            self.userCLient.append(String(describing: EmpID!))
            print("Employee:\(self.userCLient)")
        }
        else{
            selectedRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            var dict = arrRes[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            let EmpID = dict["user_id"] as? Int
            if let index = self.userCLient.index(of: String(describing: EmpID!)) {
                self.userCLient.remove(at: index)
            }
            print("Employee:\(self.userCLient)")
        }

    }
```